# How to use existing webservices in Symfony2 app?

Tags: php, oracle, web-services, symfony, doctrine-orm

We have website made with Oracle. Data from DB is provided with webservices.
Now we want to start migration to PHP and selected Symfony as a destination.

Our team is totally newbie in Symfony. The question is, what is the best Symfony-way to connect our application to Oracle-webservices? Is it possible to use Doctrine?

By the way, is Symfony2 a good solution to make app which takes data from services?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course Symfony2 is a good solution to consume webservices. For example you can use the [guzzle bundle](https://github.com/misd-service-development/guzzle-bundle) to query you API:

```
$client = $this->get('guzzle.client');
$request = $client->get('http://www.example.com/')
```

Other lightweight library is [Buzz](https://github.com/kriswallsmith/Buzz), you also have a [Symfony2 bundle](https://github.com/sensiolabs/SensioBuzzBundle) for it.

Comment: So we should use request via one of these bundles instead of using Doctrine or Propel?

Comment: I don't know Oracle webservices, don't you have an http endpoint ? http://myapi/user. If you access your database directly with Doctrine that's not a webservice.

Comment: Yes, we have http endpoint, no direct access. I wonderу does Doctrine can connect to service. As it does not I will read about bundles you mentioned above.

Comment: Doctrine is a DBAL/ORM library; it can't execute HTTP request on its own.

Comment: Ok, now I understand. Thank you.